# Refactoring similar subqueries with different WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

I have inherited a SQL query that is in desperate need of refactoring.  The query (6 pages long) looks something like this:

```
SELECT (count(*) from tab1, tab2, tab3 where tab1.value1 is not null 
and tab2.tab3id = tab3.id and tab3.value4 in (1,2,3) and tab3.value3 = 15 and tab2.value2 = 10 [...]) as RESULT1,
SELECT (sum(tab3.value5) from [EXACT SAME QUERY AS ABOVE]) AS RESULT1_SUM
SELECT (count(*) from tab1, tab2, tab3 where tab1.value1 is not null
and tab2.tab3id = tab3.id and tab3.value4 in (1,2,3) and tab3.value3 = 15 and tab2.value2 = 27 [...]) as RESULT2,
...[AD NAUSEAM for several more columns]
UNION
SELECT [same as first query, but now tab1.value1 is NULL]
...[now sum()]
FROM DUAL [of course!]
```

The end result of this mess is a 2 row / 16 column result, where the rows differ by whether or not tab1.value1 is null in the (mostly copy and pasted) subquery and the columns differ by small arbitrary variations in the other values of WHERE clause of the subquery.

```
             RESULT1  RESULT1_SUM  RESULT2  RESULT2_SUM ...
IS_NOT_NULL       300       120000     90         80000
IS_NULL            70        90000     54         95000
```

I must replicate this same output.  My first instinct is to pull out the common elements of the subquery into a WITH clause. But I'm stuck on how to get the replicate the "minor variations of WHERE clause -> different named columns" element without using a separate subquery for each column.

Should I just suck it up and dump the subquery into a global temporary table or is there a better way?

Comment: CAn you make it work with Case statments instead of subqueries?

Comment: Okay, I discovered that I can have multiple subqueries, without joining them, in the FROM clause, allowing me to set my column names there, and still able to factor out the common parts of the subquery into a WITH clause.
It's still a fair bit of redundancy, but looking better, at least.

Comment: @HLGEM, Maybe for the sum parts, but it would look messy.  I've never seen CASE statements in the COUNT() aggregates... does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main differences between the columns is `tab2.value2`, then you could write a query consisting of two stages:

1. Inner query for select the relevant data and grouping it by `tab2.value2`
2. Outer query for assigning the result to columns

So for the first half of your query it could look like this:

```
select
  sum(case when val = 10 then cnt end) as RESULT1,
  sum(case when val = 10 then sm  end) as RESULT1_SUM,
  sum(case when val = 15 then cnt end) as RESULT2,
  sum(case when val = 15 then sm  end) as RESULT2_SUM,
  ...
from (
  select tab2.value2 as val, count(*) as cnt, sum(tab3.value5) as sm
  from tab1, tab2, tab3
  where tab1.value1 is not null 
    and tab2.tab3id = tab3.id
    and tab3.value4 in (1,2,3)
    and tab3.value3 = 15
  group by tab2.value2
)
```

Comment: I didn't know the "case" thing would work with COUNT()!  Excellent. I was confused at first as to the inner query part, but now it makes sense.

Comment: One thing, shouldn't RESULT1 now be the sum() of cnts, and RESULT1_SUM be the sum of sms?

Comment: ANd of course, I must point out that the use of implicit joins is a SQL antipattern and if they database supports explicit joins they should be used to prevent the errors (accidental cross joins) and problems (such as adding left joins in maintenance and starting tog et incorrect results)of implicit joins. I know Oracle went to explict joins late, but stillthey have had them for years. It is time to stop using a code pattern that was repleced with something better in the last century.

Comment: @HLGEM, good point -- now that I've fixed the more... egregious copy and paste issues, making the joins explicit is a lot easier, and should be done.